# Refactoring issue (Netbeans 8.1)

Tags: php, netbeans, ide, refactoring

Im using netbeans to develop some of my php projects. Everything worked fine until it received version 8.1 updates.

Now, when i try to refactor a class method for example, it pops a message `"You can not refactor because this file is not part of an open project"`
(I don't know if it says the exact same words in the english version because it's installed with my native lang pack)

I just tried to exclude the entire project and did my checkout again (Im using subversion as version control for this project), but it keeps blocking me from refactoriong.

**I am sure those files are part of an open project** . Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Any help would be very appreciated.

~Edit:

Example of refactoring:

I have this public method inside my "Controller" class:

```
   /**
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAll(){
        return $this->_controllerData;
    }
```

Just trying to rename it to **getData** instead.
(Right click the method name then go to *Refactor > Rename (Ctrl+R)*

Comment: Looks like a bug in Netbeans 8.1 (I am probably point out the obvious)

Comment: Is this happening to you too?

Comment: I tried to rename a method refactor and it worked. Can you edit the question and add some sample code and the exact refactor you did ? (rename,move,copy)

Comment: It worked when tried to rename a private attribute $_controllerData to $_data but it keepspoping that message when it is a public or protected method/attribute @rjdkolb

Comment: And this is the project Im working on: https://github.com/xxnoobmanxx/corvi

Comment: You are right. When I rename refactor a public method a blank dialog appears "Refactoring..." definitely a bug. Please log with the NB team and post it here

Comment: I didn't knew if it was really an issue or something with this project. I will just report it. Thank you for the assistance

Comment: Here is the report link: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=257661